# rsnapshot through nfs: failed to preserve ownership|cannot access errors

Tags: nfs, systemd, nfs4, rsnapshot

Trying to rsnapshot to an nfs share I get some ownership and access errors, even if I can visibly do any operation on my shares with UID 1000 and GID 1000 on both server/client.

### Server exports

/etc/exports

```
# Data (insecure for MACOS clients)
/mnt/data       172.16.10.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure)
```

### Client mounted directory

/etc/systemd/system/mnt-data.mount

```
[Unit]
Description=ServerData
After=network.target

[Mount]
What=172.16.10.171:/mnt/data
Where=/mnt/data
Type=nfs
Options=_netdev,auto

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Error got in crons

```
require Lchown
Lchown module loaded successfully
Setting locale to POSIX "C"
echo 24722 > /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
mv /mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.1/ /mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.2/
/bin/cp -al /mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.0 \
    /mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.1
/bin/cp: cannot access '/mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.0/localhost/usr': Permission denied
/bin/cp: failed to preserve ownership for '/mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.1/localhost/usr': Operation not permitted
/bin/cp: cannot access '/mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.0/localhost/var': Permission denied
/bin/cp: failed to preserve ownership for '/mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.1/localhost/var': Operation not permitted
/bin/cp: failed to preserve ownership for '/mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.1/localhost': Operation not permitted
/bin/cp: failed to preserve ownership for '/mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.1': Operation not permitted
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
rsnapshot encountered an error! The program was invoked with these options:
/usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: /bin/cp -al /mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.0 /mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.1 failed (result 256, exit status 1).
ERROR: Error! cp_al("/mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.0/", "/mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.1/")
/usr/bin/logger -p user.err -t rsnapshot[24722] /usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha: \
    ERROR: Error! cp_al("/mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.0/", \
    "/mnt/backups/vmDebDevSrv1/alpha.1/")
rm -f /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure but adding `vers=3` as mount option solved my issue, as mentionned in many parts the version 4 of nfs server does manage rights through ACL....

So my `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-data.mount` should look like

```
[Unit]
Description=ServerData
After=network.target

[Mount]
What=172.16.10.171:/mnt/data
Where=/mnt/data
Type=nfs
Options=_netdev,auto,vers=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```